# Javascript JSON delete [] elements

Tags: javascript, json, is-empty

I've got the following JSON:

```
{
  "BTC_1CR": [],
  "BTC_ABY": [],
  "BTC_AC": [],
  "BTC_ADN": [],
  "BTC_PLX": [
    {
      "orderNumber": "4953620",
      "type": "sell",
      "rate": "0.00000597",
      "amount": "653.85639346",
      "total": "0.00390352",
      "date": "2014-05-30 22:44:40"
    }
  ],
  "BTC_PMC": [],
  "BTC_PPC": []
}
```

I need to get rid of the empty [] elements..

Comment: And what is your question? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that data, this should work:

```
for(var key in json){
    if(json[key].length == 0) delete json[key];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to delete something from a dictionary (which is where you're getting stuck, I think) just do `delete dictionary[key]`

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript you can try with clean code, making that JSON with the variable yourJSONData:

```
//declare the new object filtered
var JSONwithoutEmptys = {};
for(var key in yourJSONData){
  var item = yourJSONData[key]; 
  if(isArray(item)){
     if(item.length > 0){
         JSONwithoutEmptys[key] = item;
     }
   } else {
      JSONwithoutEmptys[key] = item;
   }
}

function isArray(element){
   var result = false;
   if(Object.prototype.toString.call( element) === "[object Array]"){
      result = true;
   }
   return result;
}
//then you can use JSONwithoutEmptys so clear :D
```